# Custom field validation in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am coding an app with DRF where ab User can write a review and add pictures to it.

Here are my models:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    maps = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
                 

class RestaurantReview(models.Model):    
    review_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class StarterPic(models.Model):
    restaurant_review = models.OneToOneField(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture = models.ImageField()
```

I have one model for each type of pictures (inside, outside, starter, main course, dessert...) but didn't put them for the sake of readability.

My serializers:

```
class RestaurantIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        field = fields = '__all__'


class RestaurantReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = RestaurantReview
        field = fields = '__all__'  


class StarterPicsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StarterPic
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate_restaurant_review(self, value):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not value in user.restaurantreview_set.values_list('restaurant_id', flat=True): 
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User has not reviewed the restaurant')        
        return value
```

My views:

```
class RestaurantIdViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Restaurant.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantIdSerializer


class RestaurantReviewViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.RestaurantReview.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.RestaurantReviewSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,IsAuthorOrReadOnly]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(review_author=self.request.user)


class StarterPicsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.StarterPic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StarterPicsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

My issue is that I want only the author of the review to post a picture on the review. With the validate_restaurant_review I am using, no one can post a picture on a review, even the author.

How should I rewrite my `validate_restaurant_review` ?

Comment: If the review is not saved yet when starter pic is uploaded, then the author hasn't written anything yet and the validator is correct. But if it saved, then `if RestaurantReview.objects.filter(pk=value, user=user).exists():` is a better test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right path, just need to compare the id of the review author with id of the user in the request object

```
def validate_restaurant_review(self, value):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if user.pk != value.review_author_id: 
        raise serializers.ValidationError('the review belongs to a different user')        
    return value
```